# Lisp's apply and funcall vs Python's apply

Tags: python, lisp, common-lisp, python-2.x

Lisp's APPLY is for calling functions with computed argument stored in lists.(Modified from Rainer's comment)

For example, the following code changes (list 1 2 3) to (+ 1 2 3).

```
(apply #'+ '(1 2 3))
```

However, Python's apply does what Lisp's funcall does, except for some minor differences (input is given as tuple/list)

```
(defun add (x y) (+ x y))
(funcall #'add 1 2) 
or
(funcall #'(lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 10 2)
```

```
apply(lambda x,y : x+y, [1,2])
```

What do you think? Are there more differences between Lisp's funcall and Python's apply?

Comment: Note that you can also do `operator.add(*[1,2])` instead of `1+2`. Obfuscation much?

Comment: No, Lisp's APPLY is not for replacing the first element in a list. Lisp's APPLY is for calling functions with computed argument lists stored in lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any reason why Python chose the name apply not funcall?

Because it's Python, not LISP. No need to have the same name, `funcall` is a LISP command and `apply` is something different in Python.

`apply` is deprecated in Python, use the extended call syntax.

Old syntax:

```
apply(foo, args, kwargs)
```

New syntax:

```
foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Common Lisp `(funcall #'fun 1 (list 2 3 4))` is exactly the same as `(fun 1 (list 2 3 4))`, whereas `(apply #'fun 1 (list 2 3 4))` would mean different things depending on the arity of fun.

```
* (defun bleargh (a &rest b) (cons a b))

BLEARGH
* (funcall #'bleargh 1 (list 1 2 3))

(1 (1 2 3))
* (apply  #'bleargh 1 (list 1 2 3))

(1 1 2 3)
```

So FUNCALL and APPLY do very different things, as it were.

Answer (score 2):

[Just a note](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply):

> *Deprecated since version 2.3*: Use the extended call syntax with `*args` and `**keywords` instead.

removed in py3k.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you claim Lisp's `apply()` would do anything different than Python's. Both functions take a function and a list and then call the function with the list elements as arguments. (`(+ 1 2 3)` *is* an call to `+` with arguments `1`, `2` and `3`, isn't it?) To me it looks like both `apply`s do exactly the same thing.

`funcall` on the other hand tales a function and several separate arguments (not a list containing arguments) and applies the function to these arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Both Lisp's and Python's apply function do the same thing -- given a function f and a list of parameters p, apply f to p.  The only difference is that Python's apply also accepts a dictionary for keyword arguments.  In Lisp, these would be included in the parameter list as `:keyword` arguments.